# I can't understand why one member function (A) is being called instead of another (D)

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to understand some code I came across.

My question is why `a1->h()` calls the member function `h()` in struct `A` instead of the one in struct `D`. Here's the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int i;
    A(int value) : i{value}{}
    virtual int f()  {return 1 + i;}
    virtual int g() {return 2+ i;}
    int h() {return 3+i;}
};

struct B : virtual A {
    B() : A(10000) { }
    int f() override { return 20; }
    int h() { return 100+A::i; }
};

struct C : virtual A {
    C() : A(-10) { }
    int g() override { return 30; }
    int h() { return 300+A::i; }
};

struct D : B, C {
    D() : A(-5) { }
    int h() { return 50+A::i; }
};


int main()
{
    D d; 
    A *a1 = &d; 

    std::cout << a1->f() << ',' << a1->g() << ',' << a1->h() 
              << '\n'; 
}
```

The output is:

```
20,30,-2
```

Comment: h() isn't a virtual function. a1 is typed as an A* . a1->h() refers to the member fcn of struct A and can be resolved at compile time based on the type (of a1) with no virtual lookup needed. Now if it was virtual, that would be a different story.

Comment: This is why you should always use the `override` keyword when you think you're overriding a function.  The compiler would have caught this issue if `D::h` had been marked `override` since it isn't overriding anything.

Comment: BTW: You are overcomplicating this using four classes and virtual inheritance. Same general behaviour using just one base and one derived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your base class A does not have the `virtual` keyword on `int h()` then it will not be overriden by D.  I believe adding `virtual` to the base class `virtual int h()` will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: You surely don't mean adding `virtual` to a class anywhere but rather to a memberfunction within a class. As it's written, it's really confusing.

Comment: The question was specifically about the int h() function so i was referring to adding virtual to int h() in class A